# Are non-top-level functions members of any object?

Tags: javascript

I know that top-level functions are members of the `window` object, and it's consistent with the fact that `this` inside them refers to the `window`.

But for non-top level functions, `this` is still `window`, but they are not members of `window`!

Here's some code:

```
function topLevel1() {
    alert(this)
}

function topLevel2() {
    function inner() {
        alert(this)
    }

    inner()
}

topLevel1()                // alerts DOMWindow
alert(window.topLevel1)    // alerts text of topLevel1, as expected

topLevel2()                   // again, alerts DOMWindow
alert(window.inner)           // undefined
alert(window.topLevel2.inner) // undefined
```

1. If `inner` is neither a member of `window` nor of `topLevel2`, whose member is it?
2. How can it be that it's `this` is `window`, but it's not a `window`'s member?
3. Isn't it a law in Javascript that if `this == owner`, then the current method was called via `owner.`? (except special cases like constructors, `apply`, `call`, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, the `this` value of a function is decided of **how** the function is invoked, not where it is located or how it was designed.

If you just call a function

```
foobar()
```

anywhere in your code, just like that, its `this` value will always be `window` (non-strict mode) or `undefined` (strict). Now there are plenty of ways to modify the `this`, like calling the function with `.apply()`, `.call()` or `.bind()`. All of those methods give your the opportunity to modify the `this` value for a given function. Also, if you call a function with the `new` keyword, `this` referes to a newly created object (which is also returned).

So, location of a function tells you zero about its context or `this`.

Now to answer your specific questions:

1. `inner` is a member of the `Activation Object` from `topLevel2` (ES3)
2. described above
3. I guess thats also covered above

Comment: Though I don't understand why JS doesn't then allow syntax `obj.f` for invoking named function `f` with `this == obj`.

Comment: Disregard that, I got it, `.` is only for member access.

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic reference of the this keyword is: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

The inner() function inside topLevel2() can only be visible to topLevel2.  It's a scope issue.  That's why you get undefined.